# unorderable types: float() <= lists()

Tags: python, gps, numbers

I cant get my code to compare two numbers all I want it to do is see if a number is smaller if it is then I want it to print "is smaller" if it is not then I want it to end.
The lat.csv is fill of numbers like 52.6169933 and the user input will be very similar.

```
import csv
lat = float(input("Enter Location Latitude"))
lat = lat - 0.01862
x = 1
with open('lat.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    arraylat = list(reader)
if float(lat) <= arraylat[x]:
    print("is smaller")
print("end")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ryan/Documents/python/Map/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    if float(lat) <= arraylat[x]:
TypeError: unorderable types: float() <= list()
```

Comment: `arraylat[x]` is returning a list rather than a `float`.

Comment: Can we see your `lat.csv` file?

Comment: You're reassigning lat, is that what you want to do?

Comment: Am i it should be only changing by - 0.01862

Comment: arraylat is filled with 400+ numbers like this 52.587957
55.877377,
53.4482517,
51.426814,
52.6368292,
50.5518533,
53.586458,
55.975144,
52.674374,
56.46139,
53.442474,
52.488997,
52.632917,
52.5710942,
51.473009,
53.637264,

Comment: if you need to see the whole code just ask i trimmed it down for here

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues with the example code you put up, which you should be able to fix yourself if you go through any Python tutorial for beginners.
Assuming I understand your problem,

```
with open('lat.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        row = row.split(',')
        is_smaller = False
        for val in row:
            if(lat <= float(val)):
               print("is smaller")
               is_smaller = True
               break
        if is_smaller == True:
            break
print("end")
```

the is_smaller flag check if a value larger than input is found, and if it is, it stops searching and prints "is smaller"
it would be helpful for you to read up on [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: I do not think this solves the issue. Here, `arraylat` is probably a 2-or-more-dimensional array, hence, `reader` must have been as such as well. By iterating through `reader`, you are essentially getting the inner arrays stored into `row`, then attempting to convert a `list` to a `float` using `float(row)` will cause a `TypeError`.

Comment: Does this cycle through all of lat.csv as i need to compare the user input with every single row. and print every match.  i don't understand why you use row[0] should it be row[x] and then you could increase x by 1 to go through the list?

Comment: Hope these changes help!